Wannier90: assigning Wannier functions to entangled bands
I'm trying to use Wannier90 to calculate the Wannier functions of 4 entangled bands for a material I believe to be well-described by $sp^3$ orbitals. After pre-processing and running pw2wannier90.x, there exists the following lines in my seedname.wout file:
 Calculating interpolated band-structure

 Time to calculate interpolated band structure       0.748 (sec)

      Wannier Function Num:    1       Maximum Im/Re Ratio =    0.000028
      Wannier Function Num:    2       Maximum Im/Re Ratio =    0.000040
      Wannier Function Num:    3       Maximum Im/Re Ratio =    0.000044
      Wannier Function Num:    4       Maximum Im/Re Ratio =    0.000040

My question is: by "Wannier function No. 1", does the program refer to the Wannier function of the lowest-energy band, and so on for the other three functions? How do I know which Wannier function belongs to which band?

It will definitely be the wavefunctions as they are saved out, and yes, I think the obvious ordering is from lowest energy upwards. However, I think you should never accept "believe to be well-described". You should do the projections from QE before you attempt wannierisation.

I agree completely with not accepting "believed to be well-described". Could you possibly elaborate on "doing the projections from QE"? My workflow leading to the *.wout file in the OP was:

scf
nscf
wannier90.x -pp
pw2wannier90.x
wannier90.x


Before you do the wannier but after you have the SCF, you should try the projections. Use projwfc.x and make sure that the pseudopotentials that you are using, have enough atomic wavefunctions in them that you can project the Bloch wavefunctions in terms of them. That the sum of the projections is nearly 1. Otherwise, wannierisation will fail.

If you don't care about actually having an $sp^3$ function at the end, you can use the automated scdm method. https://www.nature.com/articles/s41524-020-0312-y I wrote a script that fits the two adjustable parameters described in their paper, so it really is just ready to use right out of the box. I can share it with you. It has worked exceptionally well for me even disentangling 44 bands out of a manifold of 65 bands.

Also, I think if you define projections, the ordering of wannier functions in .wout is the order of projections that you defined. I am pretty certain of this.
